# Using firefox streamId to stream screenshare

Tags: javascript, firefox, webrtc

Hello i have this promise:

```
var p = navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(screencast)
.then(stream =>{
    console.log(stream);
    screencast = {
        audio: false,
        video: {
            streamId: stream.id,
            mediaSource:"screen" || "window"
        } 
    }
    setMediaConstraints(screencast, 'screen')
    startScreen()
})
.catch(err => 
    console.log("ERROR: ", err)
)
```

startScreen is where i use the media constraints generated and saved in the object returned by getMediaConstrains to stream my screen

```
ICE failed, see about:webrtc for more details
```

So i was wondering, maybe i'm not using the stream.id returned by the promise in the proper place, for chrome i do a:

```
screencast = {
    audio: false,
    video: {
        mandatory: {
            chromeMediaSourceId: stream.id,
            chromeMediaSource: "screen"
        }
    }
```

Am i doing something wrong in firefox?  because in chrome you have to use the extension to send you the stream event with its id but in firefox the extension has to enable permisions so you can use getUserMedia to generate this stream object so maybe i am missing something important since i select the screen but im not able to stream anything...

Thanks for any help!

Additional info:

about:webrtc

```
(turn/INFO) TURN(relay(IP4:192.168.56.1:64862/UDP|numb.viagenie.ca:3478)): cancelling

(turn/WARNING) ICE-CANDIDATE(relay(IP4:192.168.56.1:64862/UDP|numb.viagenie.ca:3478)): nr_turn_allocated_cb called with state 4

(turn/WARNING) ICE-CANDIDATE(relay(IP4:192.168.56.1:64862/UDP|numb.viagenie.ca:3478)): nr_turn_allocated_cb failed

(stun/INFO) STUN-CLIENT(CkDk|IP4:192.168.56.1:64859/UDP|IP4:mediaserverip.com:42410/UDP(host(IP4:192.168.56.1:64859/UDP)|candidate:4 1 UDP 1677722111 mediaserverip.com 42410 typ srflx raddr 10.240.0.3 rport 42410)): Timed out

(ice/INFO) ICE-PEER(PC:1463046096935000 (id=76 url=https://localhost/tester):default)/CAND-PAIR(CkDk): setting pair to state FAILED: CkDk|IP4:192.168.56.1:64859/UDP|IP4:mediaserverip.com:42410/UDP(host(IP4:192.168.56.1:64859/UDP)|candidate:4 1 UDP 1677722111 mediaserverip.com 42410 typ srflx raddr 10.240.0.3 rport 42410)

(stun/INFO) STUN-CLIENT(IG6a|IP4:192.168.0.105:64860/UDP|IP4:mediaserverip.com:42410/UDP(host(IP4:192.168.0.105:64860/UDP)|candidate:4 1 UDP 1677722111 mediaserverip.com 42410 typ srflx raddr 10.240.0.3 rport 42410)): Timed out

(ice/INFO) ICE-PEER(PC:1463046096935000 (id=76 url=https://localhost/tester):default)/CAND-PAIR(IG6a): setting pair to state FAILED: IG6a|IP4:192.168.0.105:64860/UDP|IP4:mediaserverip.com:42410/UDP(host(IP4:192.168.0.105:64860/UDP)|candidate:4 1 UDP 1677722111 mediaserverip.com 42410 typ srflx raddr 10.240.0.3 rport 42410)

(ice/INFO) ICE-PEER(PC:1463046096935000 (id=76 url=https://localhost/tester):default)/STREAM(1463046096935000 (id=76 url=https://localhost/tester) aLevel=0)/COMP(1): All pairs are failed, and grace period has elapsed. Marking component as failed.

(ice/INFO) ICE-PEER(PC:1463046096935000 (id=76 url=https://localhost/tester):default): all checks completed success=0 fail=1
```

Comment: what does `about:webrtc` tell you about the problem?

Comment: so i just checked and i found a few setting pair to state FAILED, Timed out, nr_turn_client_error_cb, with turn, ice and stun which is weird because in chrome this doesnt happen, could this be a network config problem?? im a little lost now

Comment: I am guessing your issue is more with PeerConnection and ICE candidates and less to do with firefox screensharing, you are able to see the `stream` object in console.log right?

Comment: Please clarify your question, as you are mixing two problems here that don't need to be mixed. Can you view the screenshare in a local HTMLVideoElement? If so, then you're screensharing successfully. Are you able to send a regular camera stream across a PeerConnection successfully? Isolate.

Comment: Sorry about that, i thought my problem was inside the media constraints because of the difference between chrome and FF, yes indeed im able to view the screenshare in a local html video elment and im able to send the camera throught the same app i'm making but i'm not calling another user or someone in specific im just recording my screen in a server, this works OK in chrome without problems but in FF i'm getting that message and not being able to record the screen

Comment: If you want to ask about RTCPeerConnection then please post code relevant to that, and leave out the screensharing. Otherwise how can we tell what you're doing wrong? Also, there's no constraint called `streamId` in Firefox.